# How do I define a command for each of the options?

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers, add-on, properties

I created a dropdown using dynamic property. How can I set it so that, for example, I can apply that modifier to the name of one of the modifiers selected in the list, but unfortunately I can not get information about the selected dropdown option.
This is my code, thank you

```
 bl_info = {
    "name": "Test Add ons",
    "blender": (2,91,2),
    "category":"Object",
}

import bpy


class ApplyAll_OT_ModB(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "applyallmodifiers.func_2"
    bl_label = "ApplyAllModifiers"
    


    
    def execute(self,context):
        def ShowMessageBox(message = "", title = "Message Box", icon = 'INFO'):

            def draw(self, context):
                self.layout.label(text=message)

            bpy.context.window_manager.popup_menu(draw, title = title, icon = icon)

        try:
            for item in bpy.context.object.modifiers.items():
                print("type: ",type(item[0]),"name: ",item[0])
                bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=item[0])
        except RuntimeError as ex:
            ShowMessageBox("Please be sure of the modifiers setting", "Error", 'ERROR')

        
        return {'FINISHED'}
            
class LayoutPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Apply Modifiers"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "modifier"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        row = layout.row()
        layout.label(text="Choose your modifier to apply")
        row.operator_menu_enum("object.select_object", "select_Modifiers", text=WriteSelectObject.bl_label)
        layout.operator(ApplyAll_OT_ModB.bl_idname)
        
class WriteSelectObject(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.select_object"
    bl_label = "Select object"
    #items = [(str(i),x.name,x.name) for i,x in enumerate(bpy.data.objects)]
    #print(items)
    Ml = []
    
    def MoLi(self,context):
        Ml = [item[0] for item in bpy.context.object.modifiers.items()]
        itemsL = [('OP'+str(i),x,x) for i,x in enumerate(Ml)]
        #print(itemsL)
        return itemsL
    select_Modifiers : bpy.props.EnumProperty(items = MoLi)
    
def register():
    
    bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutPanel) 
    bpy.utils.register_class(WriteSelectObject)    
    bpy.utils.register_class(ApplyAll_OT_ModB) 
      
    
 
def unregister():
    
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LayoutPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(WriteSelectObject)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ApplyAll_OT_ModB)
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One operator.**

*Rather than communicate enums between two operators, can add logic to use one.*

[image]

If I understand the question properly, either wish to apply (try) all modifiers or one of all using the enum.

For this example have expanded the enum, and added the ALL option to the enum, tested for it.

*In hindsight prob should have named the enum `modifier`*

Other options to consider would be to have an operator boolean property to apply all.  Operator properties can be passed via layout with

```
op = layout.operator("foo.bar")
op.apply_all = True
```

to have a button to call same operator but do something different.

Test script.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Test Add ons",
    "blender": (2,91,2),
    "category":"Object",
}

import bpy

class ModifiersBase:
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        ob = context.object
        return ob and ob.modifiers    

class ApplyModifiersOperator(ModifiersBase, bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.apply_all_modifiers"
    bl_label = "Apply All Modifiers"
        
    def modifier_items(self, context):
        ob = context.object
        items = []
        for m in ob.modifiers:
            items.append((m.name, m.name, m.type))
        items.append(None)
        items.append(("ALL", "ALL", "Apply All Modifiers"))
        return items
    
    modifiers : bpy.props.EnumProperty(
            items=modifier_items,
            )         

    def execute(self,context):
        ob = context.object
        wm = context.window_manager
        def ShowMessageBox(message = "", title = "Message Box", icon = 'INFO'):

            def draw(self, context):
                self.layout.label(text=message)

            wm.popup_menu(draw, title = title, icon = icon)
        try:
            if self.modifiers == 'ALL':
                for m in ob.modifiers:
                     bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=m.name)
            else:
                bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=self.modifiers)

        except RuntimeError as ex:
            ShowMessageBox("Please be sure of the modifiers setting", "Error", 'ERROR')

        
        return {'FINISHED'}
            
class ModifierPanel(ModifiersBase, bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Apply Modifiers"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_apply_modifiers"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "modifier"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator_enum("object.apply_all_modifiers", "modifiers")

        
classes = (
        ModifierPanel,
        ApplyModifiersOperator,
)    
def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    
def unregister():
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: wow Thank you very much,I learned a lot with this code
 but one question, I used this code instead of that method, and the volume of my project code became much smaller.
But how did you manage not to display the list when there was no modifier?

Comment: The poll method.

Comment: I could not send but it is like this

layout.prop(context.scene, "my_prop")

Comment: ok.............